# What's wrong with subselect field from another subselect?

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables are:

- tbl_activity(id, name)
- tbl_activity_package(id, activity_id, name)
- tbl_activity_package_address(id, activity_package_id, district)

The user gives a district and I return a list of the activities that occur in that district. There can be more than one district by activity, so I will have to return it on a `GROUP_CONCAT()` later.

```
SELECT a.name, ap.name
FROM (
    SELECT apa_inner.activity_package_id AS activity_package_id
    FROM tbl_activity_package_address AS apa_inner
    WHERE district = 'Beja'
) AS apa
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ap_inner.id, ap_inner.name, ap_inner.activity_id
    FROM tbl_activity_package_address AS apa_inner
    INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package AS ap_inner ON ap_inner.id = apa.activity_package_id
) AS ap ON apa.activity_package_id = ap.id
INNER JOIN tbl_activity AS a ON a.id = ap.activity_id
```

This gives me the error: *"Unknown column '`apa.activity_package_id`' in 'on' clause"*.

---

```
SELECT a.name, ap.name
FROM (
    SELECT id, activity_package_id
    FROM tbl_activity_package_address AS apa_inner
    WHERE district = 'Beja'
) AS apa
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ap_inner.id AS id, ap_inner.name, ap_inner.activity_id
        FROM tbl_activity_package_address AS apa_inner
        INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package AS ap_inner ON ap_inner.id = apa_inner.activity_package_id
        WHERE apa_inner.id = apa.id
) AS ap ON apa.activity_package_id = ap.id
INNER JOIN tbl_activity AS a ON a.id = ap.activity_id
```

This gives me the error: *"Unknown column '`apa.id`' in where clause"*.

Comment: Surely the error is "Unknown column 'apa_inner.activity_package_id' in 'field list'" !?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry: have a look at the ON clause of the INNER JOIN of the second subselect.

Comment: It's the same cause: now you have in your second subselect an inner join of the tables with the alias names `apa_inner` and `ap_inner`. Your where clause must reference one of them, not the third one `ap`. So the where clause should be `WHERE apa_inner.id = ap_inner.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Old answer**

in your second subselect you use the alias names `apa_inner` and `ap_inner` so

```
SELECT a.name, ap.name
FROM (
    SELECT apa_inner.activity_package_id AS activity_package_id
    FROM tbl_activity_package_address AS apa_inner
    WHERE district = 'Beja'
) AS apa
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ap_inner.id AS id
        FROM tbl_activity_package_address AS apa_inner
        INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package AS ap_inner ON ap_inner.id = apa_inner.activity_package_id
) AS ap ON apa.activity_package_id = ap.id
INNER JOIN tbl_activity AS a ON a.id = ap.activity_id
```

should fix the error. But do you really need those subselects. I'm sure you could simplify this query.

---

**New answer**

Well from

> tbl_activity(id, name) 
>   tbl_activity_package(id, activity_id, name)
>   tbl_activity_package_address(id, activity_package_id, district)

and the result should produce all activities that have any package with a package address in a certain district with a list of all districts that are covered by the activity.

This query will do it

```
SELECT
    a.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT apa.district ORDER BY apa_district) AS distritos
FROM
    tbl_activity a
INNER JOIN
    tbl_activity_package ap
ON
    a.id = ap.activity_id
INNER JOIN
    tbl_activity_package_address apa
ON
    ap.id = apa.activity_package_id 
WHERE a.id IN (
    SELECT 
        ap_inner.activity_id
    FROM
        tbl_activity_package AS ap_inner
    INNER JOIN
        tbl_activity_package_id apa_inner
    ON
        ap_inner.id = apa_inner.activity_package_id 
    WHERE    
        apa_inner.district = 'Beja'
)       
GROUP BY 
    a.name
```

Comment: I need the `ON` clause of the second subselect refer to the `activity_package_id` returned by the first subselect.

Comment: in your inner join you do reference `tbl_acitivity_package_address AS apa_inner` and not your first subselect. In a join condition of an inner join of table A and table B it's of not much use to reference a table C ...

Comment: Yes. You are right. That's wrong, but what about if I do the `ON` as you said and get the `apa.id` in a `WHERE` clause? I've tried it and it is not working.

Comment: It's already there. It seems I cannot use an above subselect column in a new subselect. Is it right?

Comment: Right. But this first subselect is unnecessary. Because of your inner joins you can move the condition `WHERE district = 'Beja' to the `WHERE` clause of the whole query.

Comment: I see another problem: you're missing the field `name` in your second subselect, that's referenced by the alias `ap`. You can't use it in your field list of the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: And the next one as I try to rewrite it: from which table is your field `activity_id`?

Comment: Thanks for you attention, @VMai. I updated the question with more information about the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52444/discussion-between-vmai-and-felipe-zkn)

Comment: I saw your update and it doesn't solve my problem. It was my fault because I didn't describe all the problem when I created the question. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT apa.activity_package_id AS activity_package_id,ap.id, ap.name, ap.activity_id
FROM tbl_activity AS a 
INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package AS ap ON a.id = ap.activity_id 
INNER JOIN tbl_activity_package_address AS apa ON apa.activity_package_id = ap.id
WHERE district = 'Beja'
```

Comment: I updated the question with more information about the problem.